# knockout nested foreach don't work

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using a the following code to display users and their roles.

I am using knockout where I have two ObservableArray in my viewModel : members and roles.

I cannot find a way to send the username and rolename to the Roles.IsUserInRole(username, role) method inside the nested foreach loop.

What can I do to send these roles to each member in my model ?

```
 <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Username

        </th>

            <th data-bind="foreach: roles">
                <span data-bind="text: roleName"></span>
            </th>
    </tr>


</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: members">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: userName">
            </td>
                <td data-bind="foreach: roles">

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("UserToRole", "Main"))
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: members().userName" name="username" />
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: roleName" name="rolename" />

                        <input type="checkbox" name="ischecked" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="true" checked="@System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(username.value, rolename.value)" />

                    }

                </td>

        </tr>  


</tbody>
```

The problem is :  @System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(username.value, rolename.value)

Comment: Knockout processes templates ( foreach binding ) on a client, not on a server.

Comment: This is a single page application and the binding is done on the client

Comment: You're mixing razor code, executed on the server, with client side code.  You'll need to check Roles.IsUserInRole inside your controller and pass the boolean down in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional property to your model and fill it by invoking IsUserInRole on server side during getting that data:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var data = ...

    foreach (var role in data.Roles)
    {
        role.HasRole = Roles.IsUserInRole(username, role.RoleName);
    }

    return Json(data);
}
```